# Disable stars highlighting but enable click even for jQuery Raty plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, raty

I use jQuery Raty plugin. It's great and does most of what I need. I've been searching for a solution to not highlight stars when a user moves cursor over the control. Making it just `readOnly: true` doesn't help because it disables `click` event which I need to handle.

I tried to bind to `mouseover` event:

```
mouseover: function(score, evt) {
  this.score = 0;
}
```

But Raty doesn't promote its data (`this.score`) back to DOM.

I then tried to handle `mouseover` event to change each image's `src` attribute:

```
mouseover: function(score, evt) {
    rateControl.children().each(function(img) {
        img.attr('src', 'star-off.png');
    });
}
```

Again, no result desirable.

What way should I think to disable star highlighting without disabling `click` event on Raty?

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution. It seems non-semantic, although it works. And I definitely should have paid more attention to the last few sections of Raty manual.

To disable star highlighting, one needs not actually disable it but substitute highlighted star with default one. To do that, one wants to initiate Raty with params:

```
$('#raty').Raty({
    starOff: 'star-off.png',
    starOn: 'star-off.png',
    ...
}
```

Raty will keep handle mouseover events and change stars' `src` attribute, but as each one's the value stays same, nothing visual happens.